# Somethings wrong with Virtual Host file Ubuntu (10.04.02)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, virtualhost

Can't get a site to work.

Got this VH file, done the a2ensite and the reload, the VH filename is bemanningstockholm.nu
Have other sites that works with almost the exakt same VH-file and that domain works.

Have a folder on the DocumentRoot, checked misspellning also.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong at the moment.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName bemanningstockholm.nu

    DocumentRoot /var/www/bemanningstockholm.nu/htdocs
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/bemanningstockholm.nu/htdocs>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName bemanningstockholm.nu
       ServerAlias www.bemanningstockholm.nu
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what's in your apache `error` and `access` logs?

Comment: pastebin.com/FYngWpeq , didt see your comment thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have :

```
ServerName bemanningstockholm.nu
```

twice.

Comment: Tried remove the line and it dosent make a differences, thanks anyways!

Comment: You are defining the same virtualhost for the same port whith the same servername.